# SPARQL Query against default graph of Jena dataset

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, apache-jena

In [thingweb-repository](https://github.com/thingweb/thingweb-repository) in file [ThingDescriptionCollectionHandler.java](https://github.com/thingweb/thingweb-repository/blob/master/thingweb-repository/src/main/java/de/thingweb/repository/ThingDescriptionCollectionHandler.java)
 on line 173:

```
tdb = dataset.getDefaultModel();
tdb.createResource(resourceUri.toString()).addProperty(DC.source, data);
```

**Question:** I am trying to write a SPARQL query to run against the default graph of a dataset to check if the data is present and return that data resourceUri from the graph.

I tried to follow different tutorials of writing a SPARQL query but did not succeed so far. Any suggestion how to write a query against dataset default graph and which parameters are there in Jena RDF Dataset that can be queried?

Comment: It's not clear which query you tried and how. Basically, if you do not specify a graph, the default graph will be used. That means, it should work with any dataset resp. model

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {GRAPH <urn:x-arq:DefaultGraph> { ?s ?p ?o.} }
```

You should take a look at this part of the docs.
[Jena special graph names](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/datasets.html)